# How to increase pinging rate?

Tags: ping

Is there a way to increase the pinging rate on Ubuntu 10.04 ?

```
ping routerIP
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to increase the pinging rate?

Comment: I need to collect dummy packets data. It is better to increase its rate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ man ping
```

...

```
   -i interval
          Wait interval seconds between sending each packet.  The
          default is to wait for one second between each packet
          normally, or not to wait in flood mode. Only super-user
          may set interval to values less 0.2 seconds.
```